# Why does pointer variable change after passed through multiple functions

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm passing a variable by reference into a function, and then in that function passing the variable by pointer into another function. In the final function the variable is assigned to and when I print it out in the final function it prints successfully.

When I then try to access the variable in the outer functions the variable has changed.

The variable `p` is a local variable in the outermost function, and I am passing the address in. I don't know why the variable is changing since I am passing a pointer in.

Here's what my code looks like. I have simplified the code to make it easier to understand without needing to paste too much other code.

I pass `p` into `get_dsp(root, &p)`

```
b_error
run_activate(int argc, char **argv){
    b_error ret = B_SUCCESS;
    char *root = "example_root";

    char *p;

    if ((ret = get_dsp(root, &p)) != B_FAILURE) {
        fprintf(stdout, "run_activate: %s.\n", p);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I then pass it into another function within `get_dsp(...)`.

```
b_error
get_dsp(char *ds, char **p) {
    handle_t *hdl;
    b_e_t *b_be = NULL;
    b_error ret = B_SUCCESS;

    if((hdl = zl_init()) != NULL) {

        if (zl_get_dsp(hdl, ds, p) != ZL_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "b: Error getting p'\n");
            ret = B_FAILURE;
        }

        zl_fini(hdl);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "b: Error initializing zl\n");
        ret = B_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "get_dsp: p: %s'\n", *p);
    return ret;
}
```

In the last function `zl_get_dsp`, `p` is printed properly.

```
zl_error
zl_get_dsp(handle_t *hdl, const char *ds, char **p){
    z_handle_t *z = NULL;
    zl_error ret = ZL_SUCCESS;

    if (hdl == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "zl: zl isn't initialized\n");
        ret = ZL_FAILURE;
    } else {
        if ((z = z_open(hdl, ds)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "zfslib: Failure opening handle to zl '%s'\n", dataset);
            ret = ZL_FAILURE;
        } else {

            if ((*p = get_pn(z)) != NULL){
                fprintf(stdout, "zl_get_dsp: '%s'\n", *p);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "zl: Failure getting pn\n");
                ret = ZL_FAILURE;
            }

            z_close(z);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The function `get_pn` returns a string.

```
const char *get_pn(z_handle_t *z){
    return (z->zp_hdl->pn);
}

typedef struct z_handle z_handle_t;
typedef struct zp_handle zp_handle_t;

struct z_handle {
    zp_handle_t *zp_hdl;
    // ...
};

struct zp_handle {
    char pn[MAX_LEN];
};
```

When it returns to the two other functions and attempts to print `p`, nothing is printed.

Here's the output. `p` prints correctly once in the last function `zl_get_dsp`, but not in the outer two.

```
zl_get_dsp: 'v_printed'
get_dsp: p: '
run_activate: .
```

I have tried dynamically allocating the variable, but it doesn't help. I've also tried passing in a pointer directly, or passing in the address of a variable and it makes no difference.

I would think since I'm using a local variable in the first function that my variable shouldn't change by itself. I would understand if I was attempting to return a pointer that I hadn't passed in, but that's not what I'm doing.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

---

I was getting frustrated and couldn't make it work, I saw a post about using `strcpy`, I tried that which works.

```
char *temp_p;
// ...
if ((temp_p = get_pn(zhp)) != NULL){
// ...
strcpy(*p,temp_p);
```

Would this be because the variable I was pointing to is being changed by another function somehow? And when I used strcpy it made a copy of it so it doesn't matter that the other variable was changed?

Comment: Please avoid piecewise examples. Read about how to make a [mcve].

Comment: "*I'm passing a variable by reference into a function*" <- that's impossible, you mean you pass a pointer to it. Now, what's `get_pn()`? The error *might* be there.

Comment: have you tried running your code with `gdb` or `valgrind`? They usually give me the answers when I'm as stuck as you seem, and I can't see the error based on the code you pasted either.

Comment: @streblo Could you please finally provide `get_pn()` function so we can help you ? :-)

Comment: "I have simplified the code to make it easier to understand" Are you sure you haven't declared a variable `p` in local scope?

Comment: @FilipKočica Sorry, I added it above.

The function `get_pn` returns a string.

`const char *get_pn(z_handle_t *z);`

Comment: But we have to see all the funtion not just prototype :-)

Comment: @FilipKočica Got it. By the way, why would `strcpy(*p,temp_p);` work as I noted at the bottom? Is is the reason I thought?

Comment: @streblo Ive updated my answer. Your problem is explained at the bottom. If you wont understand ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does pointer variable change after passed through multiple
>   functions

It cant, if you dont modify the content (It might be a pointer pointing to same piece of memory) or where the does the pointer point it self.

---

> I'm passing a variable by reference

Its not possible in C, from [www-cs-students.stanford.edu](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~sjac/c-to-cpp-info/references):

> In C, Pass-by-reference is simulated by passing the address of a
>   variable (a pointer) and dereferencing that address within the
>   function to read or write the actual variable. This will be referred
>   to as "C style pass-by-reference."

---

Look at the example below, we are passing pointer through various functions, but both pointer address and content are still same.

```
void f3(char **p)
{
    printf("f3: Address: %p, Value: %s\n", *p, *p);
}

void f2(char **p)
{
    printf("f2: Address: %p, Value: %s\n", *p, *p);
    f3(p);
}

void f1(char **p)
{
    printf("f1: Address: %p, Value: %s\n", *p, *p);
    f2(p);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *p = malloc((int)strlen("hello"));
    strcpy(p, "hello");

    printf("Main 1: Address: %p, Value: %s\n", p, p);

    f1(&p);

    printf("Main 2: Address: %p, Value: %s\n", p, p);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Main 1: Address: 0x1a7c010, Value: hello
f1    : Address: 0x1a7c010, Value: hello
f2    : Address: 0x1a7c010, Value: hello
f3    : Address: 0x1a7c010, Value: hello
Main 2: Address: 0x1a7c010, Value: hello
```

---

Take a look here (inside `zl_get_dsp` function)

```
z_handle_t *z = NULL;
```

You have created local variable `z` which contains an array `pn`. Here you assign some string to `pn` which is inside `z`.

```
z = z_open(hdl, ds)
```

Then if you print it inside same function, everything is ok and string shows up

```
fprintf(stdout, "zl_get_dsp: '%s'\n", *p)
```

But after you return back to previous function, `z` is out of scope, which means the array `pn` is aswell out of scope and string inside `pn` doesnt exist anymore if you are trying to print him in another functions. If you want to return pointer to something it **cant** be local, becouse after return from function it out of scope, so you have to declare `z` as global or assign him some dynamical memory with `malloc`.

Comment: The multiple functions example would make more sense compared to the question if the function calls are nested.

Comment: Yes, I meant pass by pointer. I realize there's no pass by reference in c, but the functionality can be replicated by passing a pointer address, which is what I meant. I'll clarify in my post.

Comment: @FilipKočica Of course, that makes perfect sense. If I don't want to have to dynamically allocate memory in this situation, is using `strcpy` an acceptable solution? I don't want to have retain access to `z` so that I can free it later, and I don't want to pass it in as a pointer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If after you pass for reference, you access to variable and find changed the value memorized in the variable, then somewhere in the code you assigned that value to that pointer